# How to pivot pandas DataFrame column to create binary "value table"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, categorical-data

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

df 
     A   B         C         D        E    
0    a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  cat  
1    c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  dog   
2    e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  dog   
3    f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bird   
4    g -2.224569 -0.724929  2.234213  elephant
...
```

I would like to create more columns based on the identity of categorical values in `column E` such that the dataframe looks like this:

```
 df 
         A   B         C         D        cat    dog     bird    elephant ....    
    0    a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  -1      0       0       0
    1    c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215   0     -1       0       0
    2    e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849   0     -1       0       0
    3    f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804   0      0      -1       0
    4    g -2.224569 -0.724929  2.234213   0      0       0       0
    ...
```

That is, I pivot the values for column `E` to be a binary matrix based on the values of `E`, giving `1` if the value exists, and `0` for all others where it doesn't (here, I would like it to be `-1` or a "negative binary matrix")?

I'm not sure which function in pandas best does this: maybe `pandas.DataFrame.unstack()`?

Any insight appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `pd.concat`, `drop`, and `get_dummies`

```
pd.concat([df.drop('E', 1), pd.get_dummies(df.E).mul(-1)], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Very fast and practicle!