# How to rearrange the columns of a DataFrame into an indexed binary matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this dataframe:

```
data_in = {
    'dates': [2017, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019],
    'names': ['Roger', 'Rafa', 'Roger', 'Rafa', 'Novak', 'Dom']
}
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data_in)
```

```
>>> df_in
    dates   names
0   2017    Roger
1   2017    Rafa
2   2018    Roger
3   2019    Rafa
4   2019    Novak
5   2019    Dom
```

into this binary matrix:

```
>>> df_out

    Roger   Rafa    Novak   Dom
dates               
2017    1   1   0   0
2018    1   0   0   0
2019    0   1   1   1
```

with all the dates as index, all the names as columns, and the data being 1 if occurence of the name at the date, and np.NaN or 0 if not.

I can build the df_out dataframe with its index and columns, but how would you get the data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot pandas DataFrame column to create binary "value table"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812275/how-to-pivot-pandas-dataframe-column-to-create-binary-value-table)

Comment: What do you mean update the data? Also what should happen if you have 2017, roger 2 times?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos – not really, as I want here to convert a column with duplicates to an index with unique values.

Comment: @DaniMesejo – ''update'' the data has been reformulated. And each couple (dates, names) is unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max` for `1` if exist values else `0`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df_in.set_index('dates')['names']).groupby(level=0).max()
print (df)
       Dom  Novak  Rafa  Roger
dates                         
2017     0      0     1      1
2018     0      0     0      1
2019     1      1     1      0
```

Comment: what does the level argument do??

Comment: It create max values per index, so always maximum is `1`

Comment: @Corralien - What version of pandas ?

Comment: @Corralien - Thanks, it was nice feature, but understand reason for it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
res = pd.crosstab(df_in['dates'], df_in['names'])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
names  Dom  Novak  Rafa  Roger
dates                         
2017     0      0     1      1
2018     0      0     0      1
2019     1      1     1      0
```

If only need indicator function, do:

```
res = pd.crosstab(df_in['dates'], df_in['names']).gt(0).astype(int)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
names  Dom  Novak  Rafa  Roger
dates                         
2017     0      0     1      1
2018     0      0     0      1
2019     1      1     1      0
```

Comment: why he needs dummies? there is a difference?

Comment: @adirabargil - Sure, if duplicates then `crosstab` counts data, `get_dummies` never

Comment: if user just needs binary values, then get_dummies can be significantly faster than crosstab. Of course, this only matters if the user is interested in speed.

Comment: well you are right, the OP said he need binary.. however its still nice ansower (can produce error in other cases)